# Setting conditions in a series (if 0 < x < len_of_dataframe)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, series

I have series like so:

```
d = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 22, 'd': 537, 'e': 537, 'f': 0}
s = pd.Series(d)
```

I'd like to assign conditions so that:

NB: len(df) = 537

```
if x=0: "E"
if x=537: "F"
if 0<x<537: "P"
```

I have the following:

```
    df_len = len(df.index)
    no_of_na_empty = df.isna().sum()
    rslt_df = no_of_na_empty.loc[(no_of_na_empty > 0) & (no_of_na_empty < df_len)]
    no_of_na_empty = no_of_na_empty[rslt_df]
    no_of_na_empty = no_of_na_empty.mask(rslt_df, other="P")
    no_of_na_empty = no_of_na_empty.replace(to_replace=0, value="F")
    no_of_na_empty = no_of_na_empty.replace(to_replace=df_len, value="E")
```

However this doesn't work (for the condition if 0<x<537: "P"). The output should be:

````
d = {'a': "E", 'b': "P", 'c': "P", 'd': "F", 'e': "F", 'f': "E"}
s = pd.Series(d)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.select`

```
import numpy as np

s = np.select([s==0, s==537],["E","F"], "P")

print(s)
```

Note: I'm assuming your series doesn't have values > 537